# Scrollview does not work on viewpager.pagetransformer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-pagetransformer

I'm working with viewPager fragments with Scrollview  fade in- out animation.For this purpose i add the function on viewpager.pagetransformer.When i add this feature then the Scroll view  does not work properly(only first step data scroll ).

Declaration on viewpager:

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new CrossfadePageTransformer());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

SectionsPagerAdapter Class are:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

}
```

And the CrossfadePageTransformer class for fade in-out animation :

```
public class CrossfadePageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

    //working.....
    view.setScrollY(0);
    view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);
    if (position <= -1.0F || position >= 1.0F) {
        view.setAlpha(0.0F);
    } else if (position == 0.0F) {
        view.setAlpha(1.0F);
    } else {
        // position is between -1.0F & 0.0F OR 0.0F & 1.0F
        view.setAlpha(1.0F - Math.abs(position));
    }
}
```

How i can solve this issues?Please suggest to me.Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is `ViewPager` also implements `onTouchEvent`, same as `ScrollView`, so they are interfere each other.

I'm afraid there is no easy way to make it work, so just don't use nested scroll views.